# Best way to write millions of rows of csv in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a huge array which has around 10 million objects and each object have 11 distinct key and values pairs.

What is the best way to write the array content to a csv?

I tried using csv-writer and fast-csv - [Reference](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csv-files-with-node-js/)

using csv-writer

```
fastcsv  
  .write(final, { headers: true })
  .pipe(ws);
```

using fast-csv

```
csvWriter.writeRecords(final)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('...Writing csv Done. Check CSV');
    });
```

Both of this approach is resulting in invalid string length

> .join(RECORD_DELIMITER) + RECORD_DELIMITER;
>                           ^
>
> RangeError: Invalid string length
>       at Array.join (native)

Sample object looks like this

```
{ distance: 0.14,
a_id: 1923,
long: -122.234,
lat: 47.631,
DPlong: -122.234,
DPlat: 47.632,
class: 'secondary',
way_id: 2,
timestamp: '5-6-2017',
user: 'hello',
code: 'DS' }
```

What is the best way to solve it? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: write it by hand. don't use a library.

Comment: Wow, this is the first case where the maximum possible string length exceeded I've ever seen.

Comment: @DanielA.White is right. Write it yourself, write line by line and you'll never exceed string capabilities.

Comment: @JonasWilms What is the maximum limit of string length to perform this type of operations? like writing to csv.

Comment: @csvb array and string indices have to be integers, and JS numbers can be used as integers up to 2 ** 53 - 1, so arrays can have a maximum length of 2 ** 53 (0 is also a valid index)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot turn the whole array into a string as the string is too long to handle for js, instead you have to format it chunkwise:

```
const tick = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 0));

const toRow = obj =>
  obj.distance + "," +
  obj.a_id + "," + 
  obj.long + "," +
  obj.lat + "," +
  obj.DPlong + "," +
  obj.DPlat + "," +
  obj.class + "," +
  obj.way_id + "," + 
  obj.timestamp + "," + 
  obj.user + "," + 
  obj.code;

const formatChunk = array => array.map(toRow).join("\n") + "\n";

const size = 1000; // <- experiment with it
(async function() {
  for(let i = 0; i < final.length; i += size) {
    ws.write(formatChunk(final.slice(i, i + size)));
    await tick();
  }
  ws.end();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo java code:

```
open file
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  writeline('distance,' + array[i].distance + ... )
}
close file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string length is an issue, with csv-writer, you may issue multiple `writeRecords` calls instead of one.

```js
const BATCH_SIZE = 10000;
const batchNumber = Math.ceil(final.length / BATCH_SIZE);

[...Array(batchNumber)].reduce(
    (promise, _value, i) => {
        const subArray = final.slice(BATCH_SIZE * i, BATCH_SIZE * (i+1));
        return promise.then(() => csvWriter.writeRecords(subArray));
    },
    Promise.resolve()
);
```

But if you don't need to build up the 10 million objects array upfront and get them through a node stream, there is a more scalable way.

https://github.com/ryu1kn/csv-writer/issues/12#issuecomment-418666060

Answer (score -1):

Too late to answer but for someone who needs an optimized less time-consuming solution
All the above solutions are good but have

1. Time complexity O(n)
2. Hign Storage complexity O(n) or Hign Memory usage problems sometimes app may
   crash because of too many requests

Solution: Maintain a synchronized CSV file when a user does CRUD operations to DB for example in a put request

```
app.put('/product/:id', (res,req)=>{
    // step 1 do update operation in db
    // step 2 do update operation in CSV file

    return res.send('OK 200')

})
```

So next time when a user request CSV user can instantly get the CSV file

Happy coding :)